# What is getPublicCache() these days?

Tags: google-apps-script, caching

I found a GAS script that creates an RSS feed and I was trying to learn the language so I can modify it. There was a method used in the script `CacheService.getPublicCache()`, but I can't find any documentation on what it is other than what it can be used for in a few articles / questions (SO, [GSuite Dev log](https://gsuite-developers.googleblog.com/2011/11/caching-in-cloud-with-google-script.html) and [ctrlq.org](https://ctrlq.org/google.apps.script/docs/best_practices.html)), most of them using the same scenario of generating an RSS feed and returning it if it already generated. (Code sample from Ctrlq.org)

```
function getRssFeed() {
  var cache = CacheService.getPublicCache();
  var cached = cache.get("rss-feed-contents");
  if (cached != null) {
    return cached;
  }
  var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch("http://example.com/my-slow-rss-feed.xml"); //takes 20 seconds to get
  var contents = result.getContentText();
  cache.put("rss-feed-contents", contents, 1500); // cache for 25 minutes
  return contents;
}
```

The documentation for the current Cache service (for getDocumentCache, getScriptCache, getUserCache) uses the same generating and serving RSS feed example for using the Cache service, specifically using the getScriptCache. (Code sample from the current GAS documentation)

```
function getRssFeed() {
  var cache = CacheService.getScriptCache();
  var cached = cache.get("rss-feed-contents");
  if (cached != null) {
    return cached;
  }
  var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch("http://example.com/my-slow-rss-feed.xml"); // takes 20 seconds
  var contents = result.getContentText();
  cache.put("rss-feed-contents", contents, 1500); // cache for 25 minutes
  return contents;
}
```

As I'm not able to find documentation on what getPublicCache was, which method is getPublicCache these days?
I'm assuming it is getScriptCache as the current documentation example uses it in the same context as the other articles using getPublicCache in examples.

Comment: Take a look into https://developers.google.com/apps-script/releases, more specifically https://developers.google.com/apps-script/releases/2014#september_4_2014

Comment: The Class CacheService has no such method.

Comment: @Rubén, thanks for the answer, that helped to confirm that `getPublicCache()` is now `getScriptCache()`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [Rubén's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66402833/what-is-getpubliccache-these-days?noredirect=1#comment117396345_66402833), the Google Apps Script releases page has the answer - from the [September 4, 2014 release, last bullet point](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/releases/2014#september_4_2014).

> Replaced the `CacheService` methods `getPrivateCache()` and `getPublicCache()` and the `LockService` methods `getPrivateLock()` and `getPublicLock()` with `getUserCache()`, `getScriptCache()`, `getUserLock()`, and `getScriptLock()`, respectively. The old method names have been deprecated, but will continue to function. The new names follow the same conventions as `PropertiesService`.

By following the order mentioned, `getPublicCache()` is now `getScriptCache()`.